# django-comments-xtd clashing with wagtail-localize

Tags: django, wagtail, django-comments, wagtail-localize

I am following the official tutorial for [wagtail-localize](https://www.wagtail-localize.org/tutorial/2-configure-wagtail-localize/), and I am at the step to set up a second locale. When I hit save, I get:

```
DoesNotExist at /admin/locales/new/
XtdComment matching query does not exist.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/locales/new/
Django Version: 4.2.2
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
XtdComment matching query does not exist.
```

How can I prevent django-comments-xtd to get involved here at all?

I am using the latest versions of both packages:

```
Django>=4.2,<4.3
wagtail>=5.0.2,<5.1
django-comments-xtd==2.9.10
wagtail-localize==1.5.1
```

Thank you!

EDIT:
I CAN actually create a new locale if I do not synchronize it from my default one. When I then try to edit the new locale to enable synchronization, I get the same error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting all migration files, deleting the database and then running migrations solved the issue. Comments are not translated this way either and will only be shown at their respective locale.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using django-comments-xtd with wagtail-localize on one of my sites, but I don't translate the comments - they stay specific to the locale version of the page the comment was made on. From memory (it's a while back) I vaguely remember having a problem when translating the page that I remedeed by dropping the comments inline panel from the page. This also had the benefit of not resubmitting the comments every time the page was updated.